# python - Compare MIDI files

Tags: python, audio, midi

I want to compare two midi files in python, one file is original, and another is automatically generated.
Is there a function in python that will compare two audio files in MID format and return the percentage of similarity between the two?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Question is unclear: what do you want to compare ? The binary files ? The notes within the Midi files ? Compare only notes ? Per midi track ? Controller messages too ? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Midi, can be opened as text, so

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
#get content of each midi file
with open("file1.midi",'r') as f:
  content=f.read()
with open("file2.midi",'r') as f2:
  content2=f2.read()
#compare them with sequence matcher
m = SequenceMatcher(None, content1, content2)
print(m.ratio()) #your percentage
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

We can compare two MIDI files by grouping adjacent pitches together, and then calculating the Manhattan distance between the groups of pitches.

This is inspired by [this research paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Emichaelm/NEWWORK/postscripts/music.pdf).

```
    import mido
    import editdistance
        
    def manhattan_distance(list1, list2):
        distance = 0
        for sub1, sub2 in zip(list1, list2):
            sub_distance = 0
            for x, y in zip(sub1, sub2):
                sub_distance += abs(x - y)
            distance += sub_distance
        return distance
    
    def compare_midi_files2(file1, file2):
        # Load midi files
        mid1 = mido.MidiFile(file1)
        mid2 = mido.MidiFile(file2)
    
        # Extract notes from midi files and group adjacent pitches together
        notes1 = []
        for msg in mido.merge_tracks(mid1.tracks):
            if 'note_on' in msg.type:
                pitch = msg.note
                if notes1 and pitch == notes1[-1][-1] + 1:
                    # Append pitch to last group
                    notes1[-1].append(pitch)
                else:
                    # Create new group for pitch
                    notes1.append([pitch])
    
        notes2 = []
        for msg in mido.merge_tracks(mid2.tracks):
            if 'note_on' in msg.type:
                pitch = msg.note
                if notes2 and pitch == notes2[-1][-1] + 1:
                    # Append pitch to last group
                    notes2[-1].append(pitch)
                else:
                    # Create new group for pitch
                    notes2.append([pitch])
    
        # Calculate similarity for each group of pitches
        similarity_scores = []
        return manhattan_distance(notes1, notes2)

    original_file_path = 'original.mid'
    generated_file_path = 'generated.mid'
    
    similarity = compare_midi_files2(original_file_path,generated_file_path)
    
    print(similarity) # higher it is, the less similar files are
```